# How do I convert decimal input into an int?

Tags: android, string, integer

I have an EditText field where the user can enter his weight in Kilogram, i.e. 11.7. I want to store that in the database as gramms, i.e. 11700.

How do I convert the String "11.7" to the Integer 11700?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the value from an `EditText` use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html#getText()

```
String userInput = editText.getText().toString();
```

To convert a String into a double use the code from @govindpatel http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble(java.lang.String)

```
try {
    double kg = Double.parseDouble(userInput)
}
catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
    editText.setError(R.string.invalid_double); // Or whatever you want to show the user
}
```

To convert from KG to g:

```
long gramms = Math.round(kg * 1000);
```

You could replace the double and long with float and int if you know you don't need the precision or range of the larger variables.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what it has to do with Android?

```
int grams = (int)(kg * 1000);
```

To get text from `EditText`

```
EditText mEdit   = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext);
double kg = Double.parseDouble(mEdit.getText().toString());
```

Comment: Right, actually nothing, it is about Java. But how do I get kg from the EditText's String in your formula?

Comment: I've editet my answer. I think you now have everything

Answer (score 0):

you have to parse it to int,long or double.
I think In your case you can do this

```
double grams = Double.parseDouble("11.7") * 1000;

double variable_name = Double.parseDouble(string_name) * number_you_want_to_multiply_with;
```

and this will give a double value. So you can convert that to integer, long or keep as it is in your db.

to convert double to long you can do something like this:

```
long value = (long)(grams);
```

Hope this helps you,